# Quien+ subjuntivo

Tags: gramática

Leonardo está en Alemania de vacaciones esquiando.
¡Quien yo tuviera muchos años para hacerlo!

Me gustaría saber si es similar a decir “ojalá tuviera muchos años para hacerlo”

¡Gracias!

Comment: Tienes un error en la oración. Para que sea gramatical, debes eliminar "yo" y acentuar "quién": ¡Quién tuviera  muchos años para hacerlo!

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es que sí: ambas oraciones representan el mismo sentimiento de anhelo  por algo.

> Quién tuviera tiempo.

Es lo mismo que decir:

> Ojalá tuviera tiempo.

Es un recurso usado también en la poesía, como en este verso de [una famosa autora cubana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulce_Mar%C3%ADa_Loynaz):

```
El beso que no te di,
se me ha vuelto estrella adentro.
¡Quién lo pudiera tornar
(y en tu boca) otra vez beso! 
Quién pudiera, como el río,
ser fugitivo y eterno.
Partir, llegar, pasar siempre…
y ser siempre río fresco.

(Dulce María Loynaz)
```